# MYSQL Connector J in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, java, mysql, netbeans, connector

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and am developing an application using MySql Server.

My question is, where do I put the file? I know in Windows the connector goes in the 'lib' file of the project. Does this hold true for Ubuntu as well? If not, where does it go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time to read the documentation. From [Installing the Driver and Configuring the CLASSPATH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-installing-classpath.html):

> Once you have extracted the distribution archive, you can install the
>   driver by placing mysql-connector-java-version-bin.jar in your
>   classpath, either by adding the full path to it to your CLASSPATH
>   environment variable, or by directly specifying it with the command
>   line switch -cp when starting the JVM.
>
> ...
>
> You can set the CLASSPATH environment variable under Unix, Linux, or
>   OS X either locally for a user within their .profile, .login or other
>   login file. You can also set it globally by editing the global
>   /etc/profile file.
>
> ...
>
> If you are developing servlets or JSPs, and your application server is
>   J2EE-compliant, you can put the driver's .jar file in the WEB-INF/lib
>   subdirectory of your webapp, as this is a standard location for third
>   party class libraries in J2EE web applications.